# How can I trim trailing whitespace in Visual Studio 2012 on save?

Tags: whitespace, visual-studio-2012

Now that macros are gone from Visual Studio 2012, what is the best way to automatically trim trailing whitespace whenever a file is saved?

I'm aware that *Format Document* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) will do this, but it presumably changes the file in other ways, and it's not automatic either.

The motivation is given here:

*[Trailing whitespace is evil. Don't commit evil into your repo](http://codeimpossible.com/2012/04/02/trailing-whitespace-is-evil-don-t-commit-evil-into-your-repo/)*

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are at least two extensions that can do this. One is [CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496?SRC=VSIDE) which explicitly will trim trailing blanks on save, and the other is [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd?SRC=VSIDE) which can run the Format Document automatically on save.

To add an extension from within Visual Studio 2012, select menu *Tools* → *Extensions and Updates...*. In the window, select *Online* on the left and enter your search string for *CodeMaid* or *Productivity Power Tools* in the box on the upper right.

Comment: +1 for CodeMaid. I like this extension. It is very simple and do a good job for cleaning up files!

Comment: Format Document only seems to remove trailing whitespace on otherwise empty lines. Presumably Productivity Power Tools can only do this as well?

Comment: Is it me, or is it sad that an IDE as overblown as Visual Studio needs an extension to trim trailing whitespace on save?

Comment: I didn't like CodeMaid because it also does the formatting which I don't want, not just removing the trailing white spaces.
The answer by kekranx is better for me. I just want to do it occasionally on some files.

Answer (score 22):

Ctrl + H
Find what:
[\u0020]+\r?\n
Replace with:
\r\n
\s instead of [\u0020] delete empty line feeds, probably because it matches line feeds...

Comment: -1 Does this run whenever a file is saved, as the original question asked for?

Comment: +1 because this doesn't require me to install more gook in my development environment

Comment: Just typing a space then +\r and replace with nothing seems to work as well.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need to 'tick' "Use Regular Expressions" check box for this to work.
Also these will work (for spaces and tabs if you have both), the second one has space as the first character:
\t+\r?\n
 +\r?\n

Comment: great! may be this'll look a bit better `[ \t]+\r?\n`

Comment: Note that this expression partially converts unix to windows file endings. Change find expression to `[\u0020]+(\r?\n)` and replace with expression to `$1` to keep existing line endings.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+H, `[ \t]+(?=\r?\n)` replaced with nothing is what I use.

Answer (score 15):

You can use Mads Kristensen's [Trailing Whitespace Visualizer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a204e29b-1778-4dae-affd-209bea658a59). It has a keyboard shortcut to remove trailing whitespace from the current file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

Note: this doesn't run on save. You have to explicitly run the command.  On the bright side, it visually highlights the offending whitespace, so it's easier to identify cleanup opportunities even in code you haven't modified.

Comment: This looked promising, however it flashes red at the end of the line while typing. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/madskristensen/TrailingWhitespace/issues/9) on the topic.

Comment: Latest version will delete whitespace on save. This can be disabled. It also displays whitespace with a customizable background color.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `Ctrl+R,W`, a default option in VS, also displays whitespace, though not quite as "loudly" as the Visualizer.

Comment: Note this plugin does NOT play nicely with Visual Assist.

Comment: This extension slowed down visual studio with a large solution

Answer (score 8):

[EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) has an option for removing trailing whitespace, and it has a Visual Studio extension. You'll need to add `trim_trailing_whitespace = true` to your .editorconfig to make it work.

Comment: It seems like Visual Studio has EditorConfig support out of the box these days, according to the EditorConfig website.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022, the `.editorconfig` files appear in project directories, however, when I add `trim_trailing_whitespace = true` to the `.editorconfig` files, I see no results.  All trailing whitespace remains - even after reboot/edit/save/reboot. Viewing the `editorconfig` in VS 2022 shows all the options it supports, but does not list any trailing whitespace options. Maybe I am missing something?